# Equivalent of the following code in nodejs . I want to know what does the FirstorDefault Method does?

Tags: c#, mysql, node.js

```
int DomainId = db.Domains.FirstOrDefault(l => l.DomainCode == DomainCode).DomainId;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns the first item in the collection, if something matches the predicate. If it is empty it returns the default value. Which is null for reference types, 0 for int et cetera.